# Amchart Export Image getting chopped off

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

```
chart.export.capture({}, function() {
        this.toJPG({}, function(data) {
          this.download( data, "image/jpg", "acceptance.jpg" );
        }
     }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAX4r.jpg)

I am trying to create a PDF file with multiple amcharts and two of the charts are getting cut off. Only the left top portion is getting captured.

Comment: On further research, it sounds like the issue is because my charts are scattered over two tabs [link] https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/displaying-charts-in-tabs-or-other-dynamic-page-elements/

Comment: What I don't know is how to render the chart from an unselected tab.